# xdmp:spawn-function() Alternative

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

we have around "20 million" documents in the database and we have created badges of "10000" and use
**xdmp:spawn-function()** to query over these 20 million documents and perform delete operations according to some conditions . But running it through query console, query is getting timeout .. Any alternate option we can look for so that the query doesn't get timed-out

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";


declare variable $versionToMaintain := 10;
declare variable $batchSize := 10000;

declare function local:delete($values) {

    for $value in $values
        let $versionToDelete :=  $value[3] - $versionToMaintain
    return 
        if ($versionToDelete > 0) then 
            let $query := cts:and-query((
                cts:collection-query('collection name 2'),
                cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('version'), '<=', xs:int($versionToDelete)),
                cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('id'),$value[2]),
        cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('c:created-on'), '<=', xs:dateTime(xdmp:parseDateTime('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')
            ))
            return (cts:uris((), (), $query) ! xdmp:document-delete(.))
        else ()

};

let $totalDocs := 
    xdmp:estimate(
        cts:search(
            collection("collection name 1"),
            cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('version'), "1")),
            "unfiltered"
        )
    )

let $totalBatches := fn:ceiling($totalDocs div $batchSize)

for $x in (1 to $totalBatches)
    let $values := 
        cts:value-tuples(
            (
                cts:uri-reference(), 
                cts:element-reference(xs:QName('id')), 
                cts:element-reference(xs:QName('version'))
            ),
            ("skip=" || ($x - 1) * $batchSize, "truncate=" || $batchSize),
            cts:and-query((
                cts:collection-query("collection name 1"),
                cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('version'), "1"))
            ))
        )
    return 
    
            xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
            local:delete($values)
        })
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are running? Also, have you considered running as a CoRB job?

Comment: No I didn't run it as a CoRB job.

Comment: Sounds like you are fetching 20 mln documents, rather than 20 mln uris, but showing code would help verify what goes wrong.

Comment: I have Attached the code .. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the reason why it is taking so long and potentially timing out is that you are doing a lot of `cts:value-tuples()` in the for loop iterating over the batches, rather than pushing that work out into the spawned function that gets called for each batch.

Move the paginated `cts:value-tuples()` call inside of the `local:delete()`, and pass in the `$x` batch value, instead of the tuples.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $versionToMaintain := 10;
declare variable $batchSize := 10000;

declare function local:delete($x) {
  let $values := 
        cts:value-tuples(
            (
                cts:uri-reference(), 
                cts:element-reference(xs:QName('id')), 
                cts:element-reference(xs:QName('version'))
            ),
            ("skip=" || ($x - 1) * $batchSize, "truncate=" || $batchSize),
            cts:and-query((
                cts:collection-query("collection name 1"),
                cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('version'), "1"))
            ))
        )

  for $value in $values
  let $versionToDelete :=  $value[3] - $versionToMaintain
  return 
    if ($versionToDelete > 0) then 
      let $query := cts:and-query((
          cts:collection-query('collection name 2'),
          cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('version'), '<=', xs:int($versionToDelete)),
          cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('id'),$value[2]),
          cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('c:created-on'), '<=', xs:dateTime(xdmp:parseDateTime('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')))
      return (cts:uris((), (), $query) ! xdmp:document-delete(.))
    else ()
};

let $totalDocs := 
    xdmp:estimate(
        cts:search(
            collection("collection name 1"),
            cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('version'), "1")),
            "unfiltered"
        )
    )
let $totalBatches := fn:ceiling($totalDocs div $batchSize)
for $x in (1 to $totalBatches)
return 
  xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
      local:delete($x)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting bulk content from MarkLogic database (with a bucket assignment) is always a challenge. Like Mads suggested, you should consider using CoRB. It is easier to tune the performance with different options available.

Secondly, you can consider using a tiered storage approach - like a range partition or query partition (provided the license requirements are met) where you can archive the documents that match the required criteria to a group of forests. You can then use the `forest-clear()` to do the job for you.